# iOS: How to save, get access token from foursquare

Tags: iphone, foursquare, access-token

How can I get the access token from a foursquare request in cocoa? I am accessing this authentication to get the token from foursquare:

https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=token

is this valid?

I had also tried this:
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&code=CODE

but returns this JSON response: {"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch"}

and how can I save and get the token from here?
any suggestion guys?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client for various resources for mobile developers, including a link to some sample code for doing foursquare authorization: https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/blob/master/example/Classes/FoursquareAuthViewController.m